# Core Data add identical object to to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios9

Let's say I have an NSManagedObject subclass called `Playlist`. This `Playlist`object has a to-many relationship with another NSManagedObject subclass called `Song`. Say my `Playlist` object has one song "song A" associated with it in the relationship.

Given the example, I'm trying to add "song A" to the relationship again, a la adding the same song twice to a playlist.

Here's the code for adding the object to the relationship:

```
- (void)addSongsObject:(Song *)theSong {
    NSMutableOrderedSet *song = [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"songs"];
    [mutableSongs addObject:theSong];
}
```

Where `self` is the Playlist object. Since there's already an instance of the particular song in the relationship, another instance is not added.

What's the best way to go about doing this with Core Data?

Comment: Perhaps make an intermediate, wrapper object called "SongOccurrence". These will also be unique in the list, but two of them may reference the same (unique) Song.

Comment: @NicolasMiari you should make that an answer instead of a comment. It's really the only decent solution.

Comment: I just did; sorry. I was on my iPhone casually browsing SO and didn't feel like typing a full-on answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, the solution would be to insert an intermediate, container object in the hierarchy, to represent each (unique) occurrence of a given song in the playlist; let's call it `SongOccurrence` (`SongInstance` will do, too).

Because to-many relationships in Core Data are modelled using `NSSet` (which is unordered but also requires that each element appears at most once, unlike `NSArray`), you can not add the same instance of a song twice or more.

So, this `SongOccurrence` object would have a reference to the (unique) `Song` for which it stands (and that is stored somewhere else, uniquely -say, `Library`) and possibly an `index` attribute representing its order in the playlist.

*The "reference" can be modelled using a string or int attribute representing the `Song` object's unique ID (using a relationship would require the inverse to be set, too.  This complicates things since a given song can potentially belong to multiple playlists, so it would have to be "to-many").*

When playing back the list, you just sort the `SongOccurrence` instances in the set by their `index`, retrieve the `Song` "payload" of each, and play it one after the other.

Comment: I'm no Core Data expert, but if you spot any errors or inaccuracies, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Personally, I think it's worth modelling the SongOccurrence-Song as a relationship, complete with a to-many inverse: if nothing else, it avoids having to create a unique ID, and will help with maintaining referential integrity if you delete a Song.

Comment: Sure. I just find it counter-intuitive that the containing object (SongOccurrence) is the 'many' and the contained object (Song) is the 'one'. Typically it is the opposite.

Comment: So I decided to add a direct relationship from a SongInstance to a Song. I am successfully adding SongInstances to the Playlist, and I'm able to access the SongInstance's Song object, but only the first time. If I try to add another SongInstance with a reference to the same Song, the Song object is nil. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it! I had Song's relationship to SongInstance set "to one". Changing it to "to many" solved the nil issue. Thanks for your help!